# Particle 로 or 으로 after consonant?

Tags: pronunciation, particle

I stumbled upon what seems to be a contradiction in my beginner's course textbook.

The book explains that the particle which indicates direction, "로", must be replaced by its variant "으로" if preceded by a consonant.

However, the examples given conflict with the previous statement:

- 바다로 - "toward the sea"
- 서울로 - "toward Seoul"
- 건물으로 - "toward the building"

Why isn't the second example "서울으로"?

Comment: The rules are different if the previous consonant (받침) is ㄹ

Comment: The third example is incorrect.

Comment: It should be "로" after ㄹ (so, "한국으로" but "서울로" & "건물로"). If your textbook really says "건물으로", I'd recommend buying a better textbook - your time is worth more.

Comment: That is a common mistake even among Koreans.

Comment: Hmm... maybe I'm missing a recent trend but I don't remember anyone pronouncing -ㄹ+로 with 으로 - in my mind that's akin to mixing up 이 and 가 (i.e., very unlikely for a native speaker).

Comment: @jick Maybe I should say "relatively common" compared to similar situations 이/가, 을/를, etc, to make more sense. For example if you google "말으로도", you get 9k results (while "말로도" has over 500k results), and a lot of these mistakes are made by native speakers. That's definitely more common than 을/를, 이/가 mistake which almost never happens among Koreans - almost all such mistakes are made by non-native speakers.

Answer (score 1):

1. "no prop consonant (받침 없음)" or "prop consonant ㄹ (받침 ㄹ)" + 로
2. the other prop consonants + 으로